# My Lock screen background image is not displaying while playing music in my Lumia 525?

Tags: music, lock-screen, nokia-lumia-525

If I play music in my Lumia 525 my lock screen background will go and it will show a blank screen and if I stop the music my image is showing. What’s wrong with my mobile? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confident that you have Windows Phone 8.0 in your phone. Thus, there is nothing wrong with your phone. Go to **settings** -> **lock screen** and turn off **Show artists while playing music.**